# Upper semicontinuity of fiber dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a Zariski-closed set of projective $n$-space $P^n$ of codimension greater than or equal to $2$. Letting $(P^n)^\ast$ be the dual projective space, whose points are hyperplanes of $P^n$, let $U \subset (P^n)^\ast$ be the set of hyperplanes that don't intersect $C$. Prove that $U$ is a nonempty and Zariski-open subset of $(P^n)^\ast$.

Comment: My idea was to show a dominant morphism between irreducible varieties q.p. X and C. So that for a theorem I was sure that the place where the iperplanes don' t intersect a X contains an open set and not empty for (P^n)^*. Yet in practise I have some doubts.

Comment: Here is MO copy of the question: [Upper semicontinuity of fiber dimension](https://mathoverflow.net/q/287003) I think that [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) gives a very reasonable advice on cross-posting. Of course, you might look also at other [discussions about cross-posting on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-posting). One of the main important points there is that you should at least link each copy of the question to the other ones.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Come on help me sharing your ideas!!!!!! I have just started studying this new algebra-geometric subject..well do you want some formality? I’ d like instead some brilliant ideas !!!! Do you have any?maybe that is why Italiab culture still prevail?! Haha